# Foursquare API endpoint user/<friendID>/friends returns 0 results after friendship accepted

Tags: foursquare

I've created a Foursquare account and added a friend. The friend has accepted the request and the website shows that I've got 1 follower and that I'm following 1 person. When I attempt to access the user's friend list through the API, I find that 0 friends are returned. I'm accessing https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/99240765/friends with my current valid credentials and I get an empty friend array.

Is there a certain state that I need to get into in order to have my friend list returned through the API? have I not accepted some terms or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from the nice folks at Foursquare. The appropriate endpoint to hit is

```
users/<id>/following
```

while passing in the additional parameter

```
m=foursquare
```